# how many mapper and reducers will act for completion of a hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I configured Hadoop  in pseudo  distributed mode as single node. i want to know how exactly it will process any job and how many mapper & reducers will act for completion of the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Mappers depend on your Inputs splits and reducer depends on what you set in job.setNumReduceTasks() if not a default of 1. Read The definitive guide for more info.